# Count number of equal values in two rows in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that looks like this:

```
A, B, C, D, 10
A, B, X, Y, 10
A, B, C, D, 20
```

The first line is a template.
Latter lines are actual data. I want to count number of correct values for each line. Correct value is a value that is equal to corresponding value in the template line.
So, for second line it should be 3 and for the third line it should be 4.

I tried `COUNTIF`, but failed to write an expression for criterion. `SUMPRODUCT` also seems to be not helpful here since it count all pairs of equal values without respect to the position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this formula:

```
=SUM(--(A2:E2=$A$1:$E$1))
```

It checks if A2 = A1 etc, returns per each true or false, which is converted to 1 or 0 (by --) and then all the 1s and 0s are summed

Answer (score 2):

One option:

[image]

Formula in `G2`:

```
=BYROW(A2:E3,LAMBDA(x,SUM(N(x=A1:E1))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a multiple criterias in COUNTIF, which will return multiple result, and then you can just sum it:

`=SUM(COUNTIF(A2:E2,$A$1:$E$1))` --> result will be `3` for row 2
`=SUM(COUNTIF(A3:E3,$A$1:$E$1))` --> result will be `4` for row 3